# Quels mots sont à l'origine du plus grand nombre d'expressions françaises ?

Tags: expressions

Par exemple pour *chien* il y en a [27](https://www.expressio.fr/recherche/chien).

Comment: Il n'y a pas de liste finie d'expressions françaises donc je ne vois pas comment répondre de manière précise. Si ta question se limite aux expressions présentes sur le site Expressio, il faudrait la poser à son auteur (Georges Planelles) car je ne pense pas que la liste soit publique.

Comment: @jlliagre Quelle source se rapprocherait le plus d'une liste finie ? J'ai besoin de connaitre de manière fiable le nombre d'expression pour la plupart des mots.

Comment: Toutes les sources sont forcément des listes finies, c'est le nombre d'expressions françaises qui est indéfini. Décider de ce qui mérite d'être classifié comme étant une expression française ou pas est forcément subjectif à partir d'un certain point.

Comment: "Les mots" ne sont pas à l'origine des expressions dans une langue....voyons. Les langues n'évoluent pas comme ça....

Comment: @Lambie ah et comment ferriez vous des expressions sur le comportement des hommes sans ces animaux pour les y comparer ?

Comment: Ce sont les idées qui invitent de telles expressions ; les mots ne servent qu'à les représenter.  Les mots sont arbitraires après tout.

Answer (score 4):

Il y a beaucoup d'expressions et de polysémie pour les animaux.  Le plus grand nombre, c'est difficile à dire, mais  **canard** en donne beaucoup.

[Expressions avec canard et cane](https://poulesetcie.com/expressions-canard-cane/)

un canard:

- un journal
- une fausse note, son criard
- une fausse nouvelle
- un morceau de sucre trempé dans un café ou un alcool
- une tasse à bec pour faire boire les malades

canard boiteux:

- personne qui ne suit pas le même chemin que les autres, personne mal adaptée au milieu dans lequel elle se trouve
- entreprise en difficulté [de] mauvaise gestion

canarder:

- tirer à bout portant et de façon nourrie
- Les cygnes appartiennent à la même famille que les canards, mais ce sont des cygnes : égalité et inégalité; Proverbe turc
- faire la cane: reculer au moment d’agir, par allusion au canard ou à la cane qui plongent dans l’eau quand ils ont peur
- un froid de canard: quand la température est très basse,un très grand froid, un de ces froids qui conviennent pour la chasse aux canards sauvages
- glisser comme l’eau sur les plumes d’un canard: laisser indiférent (en parlant d’injures)
- marcher comme un canard: se dandiner comme un canard
- marcher en canard: marcher les pointes des en dehors
- mouillé, trempé comme un canard: très mouillé
- nager comme un canard: est assez élogieux
- être comme une poule qui a couvé des canards: être surpris, déçu par quelqu’un que l’on croyait très bien connaître
- voilure canard: nom donné au principe d’utilisation de petites ailes stabilisatrices

[L'expressio](https://www.expressio.fr/recherche/canard) ajoutera :

- vilain petit canard [n]
  mouton noir ; personne qui n'est pas en harmonie avec son entourage ; brebis galeuse

Et du [TLFi](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?12;s=2941294695;r=1;nat=;sol=1;) sans tout copier/coller

> 1. [En parlant d'une pers.] a) [Avec certaines particularités physiques du canard] *Un nez (...) en bec de canard* (R. ROLLAND,
>    Jean-Christophe, Les Amies, 1910, p. 1132); *ses cheveux (...) se
>    redressaient sur la nuque en queue de canard* (GYP, Souvenirs d'une
>    petite fille, 1927, p. 109); *il marchait en canard,* les pieds en
>    dehors (SARTRE, Le Sursis, 1945, p. 159). b) [Avec le comportement
>    gén. du canard] Loc. et expr. *Mouillé (trempé) comme un canard*
>    (ABOUT, Le Nez d'un notaire, 1862, p. 70). *Plonger comme un canard*
>    (Ac. 1835-1932, BESCH. 1845, Lar. 19e, LITTRÉ, DG). Plonger habilement
>    et au fig. s'esquiver, échapper à un danger. *Mon (petit) canard*.
>    Petit nom affectif souvent donné à un enfant
>
> - *Être comme une poule qui a couvé des canards* (cf. ABELLIO, Heureux les pacifiques, 1946, p. 279). Être surpris, déçu par
>   quelqu'un que l'on croyait très bien connaître.
> - *Glisser comme l'eau sur les plumes d'un canard* (cf. R. ROLLAND, Jean-Christophe, La Révolte, 1907, p. 490). [En parlant d'injures]
>   Laisser indifférent.
> - *Il n'a pas cassé trois pattes à un canard*. ,,Il n'a pas inventé la poudre`` (ROB.).
> - *On se sert des canards privés pour prendre des canards sauvages*. On se sert d'appâts : [...] ils sont là comme un fonds de magasin,
>   comme un centre autour duquel les groupes viennent se former, ou, pour
>   mieux dire, comme les canards privés dont on se sert en Bretagne pour
>   attirer les canards sauvages. BRILLAT-SAVARIN, Physiol. du goût, 1825,
>   p. 286.
> - *Pas de pitié pour les canards boiteux!* (P. VIALARD, La Chasse aux hommes, Les Fins dernières, 1953, p. 127). On ne souffre pas
>   d'exceptions.
> - *Il ne faut pas prendre les enfants du bon Dieu pour des canards sauvages.* Il ne faut pas prendre les autres pour des sots sans
>   expérience.
>
> 2. [En parlant d'inanimés abstr. ou concr.] a) Lang. cour. *Il fait un froid de canard* (PROUST, Sodome et Gomorrhe, 1922, p. 976). Il fait
>    un temps propice à la chasse aux canards; il fait très froid.  Fam.
>    Morceau de sucre que l'on trempe en général dans de l'alcool ou du
>    café b) Lang. techn.  MÉD. [P. anal. avec la forme du bec du canard]
>    Tasse à long bec permettant de donner à boire à un malade en position
>    allongée. *Elle lui tendit le « canard », le petit récipient à long
>    col* (J. DE LA VARENDE, La Tourmente, 1948, p. 156).  MUS. [P. anal.
>    avec le son discordant émis par le canard] Note manquée par un
>    musicien. Synon. *couac* :
>
> - Ce vieillard soufflait au hasard, sans faire la moindre attention à la mesure ni à l'air (...) il ne se gênait pas pour faire ce que l'on
>   nomme des canards en termes d'orchestre... BALZAC, Facino Cane, 1836,
>   p. 375.
>
> TECHNOL. Pièce d'artifice qui se lance dans l'eau, plonge et en
> ressort. Rem. Sens attesté ds LITTRÉ, GUÉRIN 1892, Lar. 19e-20e.
>
> - C. Fausse nouvelle souvent imaginée de toutes pièces et enflée jusqu'au
>   mélodrame dans des journaux de seconde catégorie. *Mme X. m'avait
>   annoncé le mariage de Sabine, mais il paraît que c'est un canard*
>   (MÉRIMÉE, Lettres à la comtesse de Montijo, t. 2, 1870, p. 16) :
> - 6. De toutes les espèces de canards, la plus dangereuse pour les journaux de l'opposition, c'est le canard officiel. Quelque rusés que
>      soient les journalistes, ils sont parfois les dupes, volontaires ou
>      involontaires, de l'habileté de ceux d'entre eux qui, de la presse,
>      ont passé, comme Claude Vignon, dans les hautes régions du pouvoir.
>      BALZAC, La Cousine Bette, 1846, p. 310.
> - Arg. Mauvais journal; p. ext., journal quelconque : Tous ces ouvriers communistes ou communisants dont je vous parlais, ils achètent volontiers en même temps que L'Huma un journal
>   d'information, mais pas un autre canard politique. S. DE BEAUVOIR, Les
>   Mandarins, 1954, p. 130.